# Distinguishing between entered commands in C

Tags: c, string, stdin

I am working on a project in C. It is a primitive file system shell and one of commands can either take in a string after it or not. Here is how I am reading in commands from `stdin`. (This way is specified by my instructor):

```
fsys* f = newFileSystem();
char cmd[21];
char path[1001];

while(scanf("%s", cmd) > 0){
    if(strcmp(cmd, "ls") == 0){
        // this is probably the wrong way to go about it but...
        if(fgets(path, 1001, stdin)){   // 1001 is max path length
            strtok(path, "\n");     // doesn't remove if path is only \n
                                    // fgets reads in \n character and it affects output 
                                    // later, so getting rid of it now
            strtok(path, " ");      // doesn't remove space between ls and path name
            fs_ls(f, path);
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp(cmd, "pwd") == 0){
        // prints path to cwd beginning at root
        fs_pwd(f);
    // some other commands in here
    else{
        printf("Command not recognized.");
    }
}
```

So `ls` can either take in no path (defaults to current working directory) or can take in a path and list files and directories at that location.

What can I write within the if statement "if(strcmp(cmd, "ls") == 0)" for the system to check if there is a path after ls or not and execute ls correctly?

Comment: u should strtok the cmd not the path

Comment: I don't see how that would help

Comment: Use `sizeof(path)` in preference to 1001; it changes if you ever change the size of `path`.  You'll need to loop and set up a list of strings (like `char **argv` to `main` - and arrange to pass that to `fs_ls()` as the second argument.  Probably you'll include `ls` as the first string in the array.

Comment: i misread yr code. I thought cmd contained the whole string. Which is BTW what I would do, you should read one whole command at once (this way you can trace it, put it in a command history,....)

Comment: Post the declaration of `path`.

Comment: I added the variables I declared before my while loop - char path[1001];